# Doctrine: return one dimensional

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a ManyToOne relation between two entities `ArticleLine` and `Artcile`:

```
<?php
//ArticleLine.php
ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gain\Bundle\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article")
```

I'm trying to get the list of Ids based on some where conditions..

This my doctrine query dql:

```
SELECT tl.id FROM AppBundle\Entity\ArticleLine tl INNER JOIN tl.turnover t INNER JOIN tl.article a WHERE t.supplier = :supplier AND t.year = :year AND tl.significant = false ORDER BY tl.id asc
```

After calling `$qb->getQuery()->getResult()` I'm getting this result of arrays...

```
array:138 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "id" => 64624
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "id" => 64630
  ]
  2 => array:1 [
    "id" => 64631
  ]
  3 => array:1 [
    "id" => 64632
  ]
  4 => array:1 [
    "id" => 64633
  ]
  5 => array:1 [
    "id" => 64637
  ]
  6 => array:1 [
    "id" => 64638
```

Any idea how I can transform my result to a one dimensional array or playing on hydration mode to get something like this

`[64624, 64630, 64631, 64633 ... ]`
or 
`[0 => 64624, 1 => 64630, 2 => 64631 ...]`

Answer (score 5):

You can transform your result with an array_map function:

```
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult()
$result = array_map('current', $result);
```

You can also use `array_column` fucntion:

```
$result = array_column($result, "id")
```

If a solution exists with an hydration mode. I would like to know :)

Comment: can you explain the stroy of arry_map and current

Comment: The first argument of `array_map` is a callback function (or function name) and there is a function [current](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) wich get the current element in an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleColumnResult()
```

Comment: Hi thank you for help, Could please specify this is available from wish doctrine version ?

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.